# Calculating area under the curve using a base line method in excel

Tags: excel, area, curve, baseline

> [image: Blockquote]

I have this data set where I am trying to calculate the area under the curve in excel ; I found an equation (C3+C4)/2*(B4-B3). I am trying to calculate the area with a baseline method where I keep one stable y-value per attached in the image below. Is there a way to do this in excel? The black line is the curve and the red line is the baseline that I want to use (not zero). Any help is appreciated!! Thanks in advance :)

[image: Area under curve diagram]

Comment: Are you able to calculate the total AUC (from 0)? If so, then could you simply take the `(total auc) minus (0 to baseline area)`

Comment: I am not sure if I am able to. I have attached some data for reference. I need the fluorescent value to be constant (my y value) and my x value can and should fluctuate.